# Make the text adjacent to my checkbox clickable

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to make the text adjacent to my checkbox clickable.
Why is this code not working?

```
<form name="f1">
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1">
<span onClick="name[0].checked=(! name[0].checked);">Add whipped cream to your drink (add $0.50)</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="2">
<span onClick="name[1].checked=(! name[1].checked);">Add whipped cream to your drink (add $0.50)</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not use `<label>` elements? It's what they were created for...

Comment: and use the for="inputId" atrribute to make them clickable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Why is this code not working?"*

Because you can't refer to checkboxes by name as an array like that. The name of your checkboxes is a string `"name[]"` that includes the `[]` characters. The browser does not consider that to be anything to do with arrays. One way that you can still refer to the elements by that name is like this:

```
onClick="document.forms.f1['name[]'][0].checked=!document.forms.f1['name[]'][0].checked;"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CYCqr/2/

...but I really don't recommend doing that. It would be easier to remove the JS completely and just use label elements:

```
<form name="f1">
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1">
<label for="cb1">Add whipped cream to your drink (add $0.50)</label>
<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="2">
<label for="cb2">Add whipped cream to your drink (add $0.50)</label>
</form>
```

The `for` attribute of each label specifies the id of the associated checkbox. Clicking the label checks or unchecks the checkbox.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CYCqr/

Or you can just include the checkbox inside the label (with or without your original span elements around the text):

```
<form name="f1">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1">Add whipped cream to your drink (add $0.50)</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="2">Add whipped cream to your drink (add $0.50)</label>
</form>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CYCqr/1/